# on click mulitple input then show button for validation jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have here three sections, how can I make the next button show up when all three sections have been clicked? If one of them is not clicked then the button with the class "hideme" is visible, if all of them are clicked then hide "hideme" and show the "third_step" button.

```
<input type="date" name="purchase_date">

<input type="radio" name="group" value="one">
<input type="radio" name="group" value="two">
<input type="radio" name="group" value="three">

<input type="radio" name="choice" value="yes">
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="no">

<a class="next hideme">Next</a><a class="next third_step">Next</a>
```

Anybody please help, I don't know where to start on this.

Answer (score 1):

Here I have add a id on `<form>`. And give the input some class .

use [Change event](https://api.jquery.com/change/) | [Show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/)  | [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

Try this

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="date" name="purchase_date" class="date">

    <input type="radio" name="group" value="one" classs="group">
    <input type="radio" name="group" value="two" classs="group">
    <input type="radio" name="group" value="three" classs="group">

    <input type="radio" name="choice" value="yes" classs="choice">
    <input type="radio" name="choice" value="no" classs="choice">

    <a class="next" style="display:none">Next</a>
</form>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.group').on('change',function(){
            $('.date').change();
        });
        $('.choice').on('change',function(){
            $('.date').change();
        });
        $('.date').on('change',function(){
            var date = $('.date').val();
            var group = ($('input:radio[name=group]:checked').val() || 0);
            var choice = ($('input:radio[name=choice]:checked').val() || 0);

            if(date != '' && group != '' && group != 0 && choice != '' && choice != 0)
                $('.next').show();
            else
                $('.next').hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply but I am using the contact form 7 and there is no ID in the form tag

Comment: @FrancisAlvinTan I have just edited my post try this

Comment: can I add another event on the condition below to hide the other button, hide ".hideme" and show "third_step"

Comment: tried this but with error  if(date != '' && group != '' && choice != '')
  jQuery( '.third_step' ).show();
  jQuery( '..hideme' ).hide();
 else
  jQuery('.next').hide();

Comment: As next button show then third step should show after click on next button

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("click, change","input[name=group],
                                input[name=choice],
                                input[name=purchase_date] ",
  function(){
     var groupSelected = $("input[name=group]:checked").val();
     var choiceSelected = $("input[name=choice]:checked").val();
     var dateSelected = $("input[name=purchase_date]").val();

     if(groupSelected === undefined || 
        choiceSelected === undefined || 
        dateSelected === undefined || 
        dateSelected === "")
     {
        $(".next").toggleClass("hideme",true);
     }
     else{
        $(".next").toggleClass("hideme",false);
     }      
});
```